# Активность Textarea при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, button, textarea

я новичoк, но стараюсь практиковаться по ходу самообучения. Подскажите, пожалуйста, у меня есть два textarea и двe кнопки, которые только визуально относятся к этим окнам. Как мне сделать активным актуальное окно при нажатии на кнопку, которая находится над ним? Спасибо

Comment: Вам надо придумать способ, которым Вы сможете логически, а не только визуально, связать кнопки и `testarea`-элементы. Это могут специальные/парные классы, назначенные кнопке и `textarea`, атрибуты `data-`, общий родитель.

Answer (score 1):

```js
// выбираем все кнопки со станицы
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-target]');

for (const button of buttons) {
  // выбираем селектор, соответствующий текстовому полю
  const target = button.dataset.target;
  // если такой селектор определён...
  if (target) {
    // находим текстовое поле для этой кнопки
    const textarea = document.querySelector(target);
    
    // если поле нашлось
    if (textarea) {
      // вешаем на кнопку обработчик события "клик"
      button.addEventListener('click', event => {
        // по клику меняем значение свойства "выключно" на противоположное
        textarea.disabled = !textarea.disabled;
        // возможно я не правильно понял, что именно нужно сделать с
        // этим полем, возможно вы имели в виду, что нужно навести фокус.
        textarea.focus();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea disabled="disabled" id="ta1"></textarea>
<button data-target="#ta1">Toggle</button>

<br>

<textarea id="ta2"></textarea>
<button data-target="#ta2">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="area_1">1</textarea>
<input type="button" class="button_1" placeholder="1">
<textarea class="area_2">2</textarea>
<input type="button" class="button_2" placeholder="2">
<script>
$(document).on('click','.button_1',function(){
        if($('.area_1').hasClass('opened')){
            $('.area_1').removeClass('opened');
        }
        else{
            $('.area_1').addClass('opened');
      $('.area_1').focus();
        }
    });
  $(document).on('click','.button_2',function(){
        if($('.area_2').hasClass('opened')){
            $('.area_2').removeClass('opened');
        }
        else{
            $('.area_2').addClass('opened');
      $('.area_2').focus();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Демо: https://jsfiddle.net/ede9k5un/

Answer (score 1):

```js
const textarea = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');

[...document.querySelectorAll('button')].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
  s.addEventListener('click', function() {
    for (let i = 0; i < textarea.length; i++) {
      textarea[i].removeAttribute('disabled')
    }
    textarea[i].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
  })
})
```

```html
<textarea disabled></textarea>
<button>Toggle</button>


<textarea></textarea>
<button>Toggle</button>
```

Comment: `i` и `i` - чтобы запутать Катю?

Comment: @Igor, это я нарочно... Будет о чем задуматься...